# set user entered time for local notification

Tags: ios, ios6, nsdate, uilocalnotification, nscalendar

I am working on loacl notification notification comes succesfully. but i dont want to set firedate for notification from picker i want to set notification firetime which user want. i have given text field to enter time and want to set firedate as per user time.

suppose user enters 1.00pm then notification comes today at 1.00pm

below is my code--

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar]; // gets default calendar
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]]; // gets the year, month, day,hour and minutesfor today's date
[components setHour:txtStartTime.text];
//   [components setMinute:12];

UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
localNotification.alertBody = txtSubjectName.text;
localNotification.alertAction = @"Lecture Notification";

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a string to an NSDate by using `NSDateFormatter` and then use that NSDate as the fireDate. However, it will only work well if the user inputs the date exactly as expected. Here is a code sample of how it works:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a"];
NSDate *myDate = [df dateFromString: myDateAsAStringValue];
```

Here is a website showing the different date format patterns available so you can create your own input style: http://waracle.net/iphone-nsdateformatter-date-formatting-table/

You should be using a `UIDatePicker` to have the user easily input dates and times. Here is a tutorial explaining how to use it: http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/add-datepicker-programmatically-and-display-date-in-iphone/